# First isomorphism theorem for inverse semigroups together with v-prehomomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, universal-algebra, inverse-semigroups, semigroup-homomorphism

In [this old paper](https://msp.org/pjm/1976/67-1/pjm-v67-n1-p09-s.pdf) D. B. McAlister has introduced a very interesting class of morphisms for inverse semigroups, called v-prehomomorphisms. For such a morphism $\theta : S \to T,$ instead of preserving the multiplication, he require

- $\theta(ab)\le \theta(a)\theta(b)$
- $\theta(a^{\star})=\theta(a)^{\star}$

for all $a, b\in S.$ Previously, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4171435/a-question-about-v-prehomomorphisms-of-inverse-semigroups) I asked a question about these maps.

Since the image $\operatorname{im}\theta$ may not be closed under multiplication, it need not to be a inverse subsemigroup of $T.$ Also, $\operatorname{ker}\theta=\{(a,b)\in S\times S : \theta(a)=\theta(b)\}$ is not compatibility with multiplication, and hence the quotient $S/\operatorname{ker}\theta$ is not an inverse semigroup, in general.
However, there is still a bijection $S/\operatorname{ker}\theta \to \operatorname{im}\theta$ of sets such that $[a]\mapsto \theta(a).$

Now my question is,  Is there any way around these deficiencies to formulate the first [isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_A_(universal_algebra)) for inverse semigroups together with v-prehomomorphisms?

Comment: Why should such a result hold? In my opinion, you are trying to force a result with a notion that is not suitable for this purpose. In other words, it seems that the only way to "go around these deficiencies" is to take v-prehomomorphisms that are homomorphisms.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: Seems like isomorphism theorems are valid in many different contexts. I really think we can do something (like with a different notion of kernals) while keeping v-homomorphisms. I don't think this question is unreasonable.